# All itmes disappear when try use searchview in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview

everyone
I have recyclerView retrieve data from firebase database

I used searchview and filter list to search item , but when click on searchview to search something all items disappear and search view not working

my main activity is fragment because I use bottom navigation

```
public class RV_Worker_Fragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerView_InterFace {

private RecyclerView rv_worker;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private ArrayList <WorkerModel> list;
private WorkerAdapter workerAdapter;
SearchView searchView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_persons_fragment,
            container, false);

    rv_worker =view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_persons);
    db =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    rv_worker.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv_worker.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            workerAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    getList();

    return view;
}

private void  getList()
{
    db.getReference("Employees").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            list=new ArrayList <>();
            workerAdapter = new WorkerAdapter(getActivity(),list,RV_Worker_Fragment.this);
            rv_worker.setAdapter(workerAdapter);
            for (DataSnapshot child :snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                WorkerModel workerModel =child.getValue(WorkerModel.class);
                list.add(workerModel);
                workerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size()-1);
                workerAdapter.getItemCount();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(final int position) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Worker_Details.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",list.get(position).getName());
    intent.putExtra("id",list.get(position).getId());
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class WorkerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <WorkerAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private Context context;
private List <WorkerModel> list;
private List <WorkerModel> listFilter;
private RecyclerView_InterFace recyclerView_interFace;

public WorkerAdapter(Context context, List <WorkerModel> llist, RecyclerView_InterFace recyclerView_interFace) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = llist;
    this.recyclerView_interFace = recyclerView_interFace;
    listFilter = new ArrayList <>(list);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public WorkerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_worker_treader_contractor, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WorkerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final WorkerModel workerModel = list.get(position);
    holder.tv_name.setText(workerModel.getName());
    holder.btn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String phonNumber = workerModel.getPhone();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phonNumber));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("حذف")
                    .setMessage("هل تريد الحذف")
                    .setPositiveButton("نعم", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference db = database.getReference("Employees");
                            db.child(list.get(position).getId()).removeValue();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("لا",null)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_name;
    ImageView btn_call, btn_delete ;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tx_name);
        btn_call = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        btn_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_deleteP);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                recyclerView_interFace.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}

private Filter filter = new Filter() {

    //run on background thread
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

        List<WorkerModel> listFilter2 = new ArrayList <>();
        if (charSequence ==null || charSequence.length()==0){
            // if search text is empty add all original list values to filterlist
            listFilter2.addAll(listFilter);
        }else {
            String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            // Perform search on whole original list
            for (WorkerModel workerModel : listFilter){
                if (workerModel.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    listFilter2.add(workerModel);
                }
            }
        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = listFilter2;
        return results;
    }

    //run on UI thread
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll((List) filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

}

what is the problem guys?
thx in advance for help

Comment: listFilter is empty because it is only set by the constructor and it is initialized by an empty list. Inside onDataChange(), list is updated with new items and listFilter should also be updated.

Comment: can give me code this will help me too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inside performFiltering() of WorkerAdapter, add the following line as the first line: `if (listFilter.size() == 0) listFilter = new ArrayList<>(list);`