# Searching makes my RecycleView disappear, already used EditText and SearchView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

My search function is an exact copy of these videos (the first link has a gDrive source code in its description):

- [How to search in Firebase database Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr4Jz5Lc5pM)  ([Google Drive code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oB_9ljVSfoLkuUGwgDqIYsporzU5BkWy/view))
- [3. How to Search in Firebase Database in Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOntdh36lZY)

Problem :
recycleView gives out no item after using searchView, the code should have worked since there is 2 videos about it. However, even by downloading their source code I couldn't get it to work.

[All itmes disappear when try use searchview in recyclerview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250023/all-itmes-disappear-when-try-use-searchview-in-recyclerview)

I think my issue is similar enough to this, however I don't really understand how it would work on my project since my adapter is different than their adapter (mine is pretty much a clone from the videos, doesn't use list).

if possible please try to fix the issue by referencing the first video source code.

Main Activity :

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
       RecyclerView recview;
       myadapter adapter;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setTitle("");
    
            recview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recview);
            recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students"), model.class)
                            .build();
    
            adapter=new myadapter(options);
            recview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            adapter.startListening();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
             getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu,menu);
    
             MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    
             SearchView searchView=(SearchView)item.getActionView();
    
             searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                     processsearch(s);
                     return false;
                 }
    
                 @Override
                 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                     processsearch(s);
                     return false;
                 }
             });
    
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
    
        private void processsearch(String s)
        {
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students").orderByChild("course").startAt(s).endAt(s+"\uf8ff"), model.class)
                            .build();
    
            adapter=new myadapter(options);
            adapter.startListening();
            recview.setAdapter(adapter);
    
        }
    }
```

Adapter :

```java
    public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,myadapter.myviewholder>
    {
        public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options) {
            super(options);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull model model)
        {
           holder.name.setText(model.getName());
           holder.course.setText(model.getCourse());
           holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());
           Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getPurl()).into(holder.img);
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
           View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow,parent,false);
           return new myviewholder(view);
        }
    
    
        class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            CircleImageView img;
            TextView name,course,email;
            public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                img=(CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
                name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
                course=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.coursetext);
                email=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.